# Hermitian Conjugate in Spherical Coordinate System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, calculus

Help me find $\hat{B^\dagger}$, when we know that $$\hat{B}=i\frac{d}{dr}$$ with the condition that $\hat{B}$ is defined in spherical coordinates. My approach: $$ \langle\psi|\hat{B}\psi\rangle=\int_{0}^{\infty} \psi^* i\frac{d}{dr} \psi dr=\psi^*\psi|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\psi i\frac{d}{dr}\psi^*dr=\langle\hat{B}\psi|\psi^*\rangle$$ And so I get $ \hat{B^\dagger} = -i\frac{d}{dr} $. Could someone confirm if this is correct?

Comment: http://www.physicspages.com/2012/09/05/hermitian-conjugate-of-an-operator/ seems to confirm the answer below.

Comment: How is |ψ|2 zero at r =0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\left\langle \psi ,B\psi  \right\rangle =\int{dr{{\psi }^{*}}i{{\partial }_{r}}\psi }=\left[ {{\left| \psi  \right|}^{2}} \right]_{0}^{\infty }-\int{dri\left( {{\partial }_{r}}{{\psi }^{*}} \right)\psi }=\int{dr{{\left( i{{\partial }_{r}}\psi  \right)}^{*}}\psi }=\left\langle B\psi ,\psi  \right\rangle $

By definition, the hermitian conjugate satisfies: $\left\langle \psi ,B\psi  \right\rangle =\left\langle {{B}^{\dagger }}\psi ,\psi  \right\rangle $. Comparing with the above result we get:

$\left. \begin{align}
  & \left\langle \psi ,B\psi  \right\rangle =\left\langle B\psi ,\psi  \right\rangle  \\ 
 & \left\langle \psi ,B\psi  \right\rangle =\left\langle {{B}^{\dagger }}\psi ,\psi  \right\rangle  \\ 
\end{align} \right\}\Rightarrow {{B}^{\dagger }}=B$

Comment: $\left[ {{\left| \psi \right|}^{2}} \right]_{0}^{\infty }-\int{dri\left( {{\partial }_{r}}{{\psi }^{*}} \right)\psi }=\int{dr{{\left( i{{\partial }_{r}}\psi \right)}^{*}}\psi }$ Didn't you miss a minus here? I think it should be $\left[ {{\left| \psi \right|}^{2}} \right]_{0}^{\infty }-\int{dri\left( {{\partial }_{r}}{{\psi }^{*}} \right)\psi }=-\int{dr{{\left( i{{\partial }_{r}}\psi \right)}^{*}}\psi }$

Comment: the minus signed is absorbed by the conjugation of the imaginary unit

Comment: How is |ψ|2 zero at r =0?